# Area of Triangle Given 3 vertices

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given that $P=(1,1,0), Q=(1,0,1), R=(0,1,1)$. I need to find the area of the triangle.

What I have done:

I have tried finding the distances of PQ, QR, and PR. I have those distances, I don't know what I do next.

Comment: use this formula $A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ with $s=(a+b+c)/2$

Comment: Try Gauss's Shoelace formula. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Heron's formula. Alternatively, you can calculate an altitude, for example, the distance from $P$ to the line $QR$.